# How to fill a digitally signed PDF with PDFtk or PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, xfa

I'm trying to open this PDF File to automate form filling: [DA1059](http://www.apd.army.mil/pub/eforms/pdf/A1059.pdf)

PDFtk, PDFBox, Chrome's PDF Viewer, and the Mac OSX preview app all fail to open the PDF.

However, Adobe Reader or Acrobat successfully open the PDF without prompting for a password.

[PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) errors out with:

```
$ pdftk da1059.pdf dump_data_fields
Error: Failed to open PDF file:
   da1059.pdf
   OWNER PASSWORD REQUIRED, but not given (or incorrect)
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

[PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) errors out with:

```
$ java -jar pdfbox-app-1.8.9.jar ExtractText da1059.pdf
Jul 15, 2015 10:41:38 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser parse
INFO: Document is encrypted
ExtractText failed with the following exception:
org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.WrappedIOException
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.encryptData(SecurityHandler.java:375)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.decryptString(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.decrypt(SecurityHandler.java:429)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.decryptDictionary(SecurityHandler.java:530)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.decrypt(SecurityHandler.java:437)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.decryptObject(SecurityHandler.java:403)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.proceedDecryption(SecurityHandler.java:221)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardSecurityHandler.decryptDocument(StandardSecurityHandler.java:158)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.openProtection(PDDocument.java:1602)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.ExtractText.startExtraction(ExtractText.java:216)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.ExtractText.main(ExtractText.java:85)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.PDFBox.main(PDFBox.java:58)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:966)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2004)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.SecurityHandler.encryptData(SecurityHandler.java:351)
    ... 11 more
```

Tilman Hausherr pointed out it's an [XFA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFA).  There's a couple of related questions on Stack Overflow:

[Combining XFA with PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536334/combining-xfa-with-pdfbox)

I started a minimal working example at https://github.com/jschaf/pdfxfa.

### Not Supported

Working with XFA and certified forms in PDFBox depends on incremental update which is currently not supported.  See [PDFBOX-2859 Support for Incremental Update](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2859).

Comment: use the -nonSeq option in PDFBox. However... the extracted text is only something telling that the PDF reader isn't capable :-(

Comment: I had a further look, this is an XFA form.